# react-native ios how to use android button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, button

[The official](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button) display two kind of buttons for ios and android, but sometimes the kind of android button is better for ios too.

How can I migrate android button to ios?

Answer (score 1):

You can find button styles [here](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html). All you can do is to style your button to give better looks. Even then they might have different display feel in android and IOS.

Comment: It can keep the feel style the same as between ios and android?

Comment: Native UI of both devices are different. There will be some difference even if we code the style to be the same @yuanlai